# In Ubuntu 14.04 few inputs are showing in system settings. Also no audio is coming out of laptop

Tags: system-settings

This is what I have in **System Settings**:

[image]

Comment: Did it always look like this? If not, what did you do right before it looked like this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't how to fix the settings issue, but for the sound issue, open a terminal and type:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

If this still doesn't fix your problem, try

```
pulseaudio -k
```

If it still doesn't work, do

```
pulseaudio
```